# get unchecked box

Tags: java, html, jsp, checkbox, forms

I have a form of a table with 'checkbox':

```
  out.print("<table><tr>");
  String box_user = null;
  out.print("<td>");
  box_user = "<input name = 'check' value=r" + id + " type='checkbox'>";
  out.print(box_user);
  out.print("</td>");
  out.print("</tr></table>");
```

I got all the checked box by:

```
String[] str;
str = request.getParameterValues("check");
```

now, I want to get all the unchecked box. how can I get it?

Comment: It was hard to do what you suggested and I tried to be prevented from it :/ unfortunately, I didn't have another choices, so I did what you suggested me.. right now, after 4 hours of attempts, I succeeded! thank you! :]

Comment: Added as answer, though I think it would be a good idea to investigate the last two sentences of the comment that did not make it into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..get all the unchecked box..

You put the check boxes in there so you must know what they are. To find out which ones are not checked, iterate the collection of all check boxes & if unchecked, add them to a second collection.

Comment: But this is an unusual use-case. Typically whatever receives the information would mark the checked boxes as `true` and everything else `false`.